# How to use class component function in function component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have this class component

```
export class Test extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array:[],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.resetArray();
    }
    resetArray(){
        let n = 100;
          const array = [];
          console.log("Reset Array");
          for(let i = 0; i < n; ++i){
              array.push(randomIntFromInterval(10,300));
          }
          this.setState({array});
      }
}
```

and I want to use this function called resetArray in functional component.. is there any way to do so...

Comment: Yeah define it inside a functional component

Comment: Take out the function from the class component and declare it outside and export. If it is necessary or needed in multiple components, then you can create a separate file and put the function in there

Comment: That's a great approch @Shuvo but then I am not able to use this.setState function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass down to Test children the any function as props:

```
render (
  <div>
    <Child resetArray={ this.resetArray } >
  </div>
)
```

at Child you will take as props like:

```
const Child = ({ resetArray }) => {

  return (
    <div>
       <p>reset array</p>
       <button onClick={resetArray}>Reset!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

if the functional component is a grandchild, you can pass down to child as props then to grandchild through child.

if component is not below `Test` tree, you won't be able to reset Test's state like that. In that case you need to lift state to a common ancestor, or use other approaches to handle state like Context API, or redux.

Answer (score 0):

> Try out importing that Test component
> from the link of that test file belong, suppose if its in the same src
> folder, do as like: `import {Test} from './test'`

Comment: let t  = new Test();          t.resetArray(document.getElementById("myslide").value);  and its shows that "Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted"  basically I have to pass the reference when calling the component.  Currect me if I'm wrong...♥